# Rails beginner - why is this controller test case failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rails-activerecord

OK, so I'm working on my first solo Rails app, a URL shortener, and I've already confused myself pretty well. From my model, I store a short URL using the `domain` and `key` attributes. Here is my model:

```
# == Schema Information
# Schema version: 20110601022424
#
# Table name: shorteners
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  url        :string(255)
#  key        :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#  domain     :string(255)
#

class Shortener < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :url

  validates :url, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :uri_format => true

  before_save :set_autogenerated_info

  def shortlink
    "http://#{domain}/#{key}"
  end

  private
    def set_autogenerated_info
      return unless new_record? #This only gets set one time
      domain = get_random_domain
      key = get_next_key(domain)
      write_attribute(:domain, domain)
      write_attribute(:key, key)
    end

    def get_random_domain
      #commented out magic to grab random domain from pool
    end

    def get_next_key(domain)
      #commented out magic to generate next unique key
    end
end
```

My current approach seems to be messing up this test case in my controller_spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ShortenersController do

  render_views

  describe "GET show" do

    before(:each) do
      @shortener = Factory(:shortener)
    end

    it "should find the right shortener" do
      get :show, :id => @shortener
      assigns(:shortener).should == @shortener
    end
  end
end
```

It is giving me this error message:

```
Failures:

  1) ShortenersController GET show should find the right shortener
     Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @shortener
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `domain' for #<Shortener:0x00000004a04548>
     # ./app/models/shortener.rb:25:in `shortlink'
     # ./app/views/shorteners/show.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_shorteners_show_html_erb___556550686459204284_38799300_3170414004415921977'
     # ./spec/controllers/shorteners_controller_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I can get the test case to pass by adding this above the `attr_accessible` line:

```
attr_reader :domain, :key
```

But that does some really crazy things like not displaying domain/key attributes in my application's views and not letting me even access them directly from the model in my Rails console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.7)
>> s = Shortener.new(:url => 'http://www.stackoverflow.com')
 => #<Shortener id: nil, url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com", key: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, domain: nil> 
>> s.save
 => true 
>> s
 => #<Shortener id: 12, url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com", key: l, created_at: "2011-06-02 16:35:01", updated_at: "2011-06-02 16:35:01", domain: "localhost"> 
>> s.domain
 => nil 
>> s.key
 => nil
>> s.shortlink
 => "http:///"
```

### Update - added view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Url:</b>
  <%= @shortener.url %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Shortened Link:</b>
  <a href="<%= @shortener.shortlink %>"><%= @shortener.shortlink %></a>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_shortener_path(@shortener) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', shorteners_path %>
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at the time

Comment: Done. Sorry, I did think about splitting them up, but didn't want to re-explain a huge chunk of stuff.

Comment: how do you define `domain` line 25 ?

Comment: Can you post your view?  Or at least the part around line 10?

Comment: Also, a couple of quick suggestions -- change the `before_save` to a `before_create` -- then you can get rid of the check for `new_record?` in `set_autogenerated_info`.  Also, having that method in your model is completely legit and probably the best place for it.

Comment: I just thought this question was for me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in the tests, the Shortener class has no access to the domain variable. Have you checked your Test DB?

Comment: Wow you are totally right, I just opened my test database and there is no domain column at all - I had added it at one point as a migration. I had no idea that `rake db:migrate` did not migrate the test database as well. Thanks!

Comment: Gotta explicitly `rake db:test:prepare` after the migration.